# Как узнать поддерживает ли мой компилятор стандарт C++ 11?

Tags: c++, c++11, стандарт

Как узнать поддерживает ли мой компилятор (у меня mvs 2010) стандарт C++ 11? А то я заголовок с потоками не нашел.

Comment: я знаю такую [таблицу](https://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport), правда там 0х стандарт.

Comment: в таблице вроде есть потоки, а вот заголовка <thread> нет

Comment: mvs 2010 насколько помнится вообще крайне мало чего поддерживает из этого ствндарта. Так что если он вам вдруг очень важен, то юзайте более поздние версии компилятора, например, ту, ч то поставляется с mvs 2013

Comment: денег нет на 2013ю. а пиратствовать не хочу

Comment: @perfect, пользуйтесь MinGW + gcc.

Comment: а ещё есть такая штука, как [visual studio express](http://www.visualstudio.com/ru-ru/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

вот ещё одна [таблица](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx), от Майкрософта. Как видите, для 2010 студии очень много No. По поводу thread. Хотя в таблице этого не указано, можно взять это косвенно. Находим в msdn страницу о [<thread>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh920526.aspx). Видим, что написано **Visual Studio 2013**. Ок, а рядом есть **Other Versions**. Открываем список и видим там только 2012 студию.

Отсюда вывод - полной поддержки `<thread>` в 2010 студии нет.